# How can you have C# find the two highest out of a chart of many and add just those for the result?

Tags: c#

So I am making a little calculator as some practice. Than I noticed I don't know how to tell C# to select only the two highest numbers entered and ignore the rest. Can anybody help me out with this?

Example:
 `textBox1` entered **9**
`textBox2` entered **5**
`textBox3` entered **7**

I want to get the two highest numbers.

Comment: ???? example??? What do you mean by '2 highest numbers'?

Comment: Please improve your question with an example for example. If you don't, your question will probably closed. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Select two highest numbers from where?

Comment: Post your code. Let's see what, if anything, you have tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the numbers in a list, like this (example hard codes values):

```
        List<int> MyList = new List<int> { 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
        MyList = MyList.OrderByDescending(p => p).ToList();
```

Then get the first two integers in the list and add them together

```
int sum = MyList[0] + MyList[1];
```

Just be sure to add validation so that you have at least two values in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help you...

```
private static int addHighestTwo(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    var sorted = new List<int>(source);
    sorted.Sort();
    return sorted[sorted.Count - 1] + sorted[sorted.Count - 2];
}
```

In your case, get the `int` values of the Text in the Textboxes (hint: [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)), then call this method like `addHighestTwo(new[] {valueFromTextBox1, valueFromTextBox2, valueFromTextBox3})`